# can't return a select query value using mysql and node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynccallback

I am new in node js, Now I am trying to set a return value of select query in mysql using node js....I am using node-mysql package...

example code

```
var mysql =  require('mysql');
var connection =  mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password: "root123",
    database: "testdb"
});

var retValue = undefined;

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tblData;');
query
    .on('error', function(err) {
        // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
    })
    .on('fields', function(fields) {
        // the field packets for the rows to follow
    })
    .on('result', function(row) {
        // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
        connection.pause();
        processRow(row, function() {
            retValue = row;
        });
    })
    .on('end', function(row) {

    });

    connection.end();

    function processRow(rows)
    {
        retValue = rows;
    }

    console.log(retValue);
```

`retValue` is always undefined. I know it is asynchronous call. anyone tell me how to set value for this variable.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Why do you want to assign `retValue` in both `processRow` and its callback?

Comment: just tried....but i can't set the result to that variable....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964988/how-to-get-the-results-from-nodejs-using-mysql-package possible help

Answer (score 1):

Since database query is an asynchronous opreation, your variable `retValue` has not been set yet at the time you call `console.log(retValue)`.

```
var retValue;

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tblData;');
query
    .on('error', function(err) {
        // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
    })
    .on('fields', function(fields) {
        // the field packets for the rows to follow
    })
    .on('result', function(row) {
        // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
        connection.pause();
        processRow(row);
        console.log(retValue); //retValue is now set
    })
    .on('end', function(row) {

    });

    connection.end();

    function processRow(rows)
    {
        retValue = rows;
    }

    console.log(retValue); // undefined, retValue has not been set yet
```

Answer (score 0):

The retvalue will available only in scope, that your put in result secion. So you can make something like that to log your result:

```
var connection =  mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password: "root123",
    database: "testdb"
});

var retValue = undefined;

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tblData;', function(err, results, fields) {
    console.log(results);
    // Here continue logic you needed with results from table
});
```

Comment: i can't get the result out of scope...i want to assign and return the value like this

fucntion() getResults{ ... ... var retValue = undefined;

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tblData;', function(err, results, fields) { retValue = results; });

return retValue };

var ret = getResults(); console.log(ret);

Comment: @DeepakSamuel node.js are working in scopes and callback maner. It's his nature. Are you sure you need to implement code in this way? You can try to sync vars via promise interface.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `console.log` inside `function processRow(rows)` so that it looks like

```
function processRow(rows)
{
    retValue = rows;
    console.log(retValue);
}
```

also change

```
processRow(row, function() {
    retValue = row;
});
```

To

```
processRow(row);
```

The second parameter was unused.

Comment: i can't get the result out of scope...i want to assign and return the value like this

fucntion() getResults{ ... ... var retValue = undefined;

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tblData;', function(err, results, fields) { retValue = results; });

return retValue };

var ret = getResults(); console.log(ret);

Comment: not working patrick....console log always show the results....but i can't get the result out of the function

Comment: @DeepakSamuel you can't get the result out of the function. That's just how asynchronous callbacks work. They're executed _after_ the outside part is executed, even the outside part after the function block.

Answer (score -1):

i can't get the result out of scope...i want to assign and return the value like this

fucntion() getResults{
...
...
var retValue = undefined;

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tblData;', function(err, results, fields) {
    retValue = results;
});

return retValue
};

var ret = getResults();
console.log(ret);

Comment: This isn't an answer.